# sharepoint performance after running batch process

Tags: sharepoint-2007

i am import list data using web.processbtachdata. it updated all data successfully wid out any error. after tht successfull import whenever i click on any list it opens very late, say 40-50seconds depending on number of columns, why is it so?
after tht frst click when i click on any other list including the current one it opens within 2 seconds or so...

em running sharepoint2007 on win 2003 server..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have too many items in the view.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28office.12%29.aspx

> Item
>
> 2,000 per view
>
> Testing indicates a reduction in
>   performance beyond two thousand items.
>   Using indexing on a flat folder view
>   can improve performance.
>
> List view

Or you are not disposing of SharePoint objects correctly.

If you can check perf counters on servers, high WFE load/mem will likely mean a dispose issue, spiking sql cpu, probably view too big.

Comment: i only have 300 items in list... plus im using spcontext fo spsite and web, so as article says "http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/Sharepoint/213_SPException_Trying_to_use_an_SPWeb_object_that_has_been_closed_or_disposed_and_is_no_longer_valid_.aspx" sugeest tht spcontext obj's disposing will direct an error trying to disose...

Comment: as u mentioned the mem usage , ma sql is not spiking but my w3wp spikes to 100%, drices me crazy